# Downloading multiple items to firebase storage bucket

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download or use an array of images that I have saved into the firebase storage bucket.

I have a form with a file input where the user can upload an image to the firebase storeage bucket and then i'm saving that firestore image link into an array called ImageArray.

When the image is uploaded to Firebase storage the file type is Image/png which is what I want. I can also get the link saved in the array and display the images as thumbnails as I like.

However when I then press "Submit" and send all form data to firebase to be saved. the image types in the array of images turn into type application/octet-stream and there for cannot be used as images. But again I have the image link saved in the firestore database.

I'm not sure why the type is changing only when i'm pressing submit and i'm only doing the firebase store handling when uploading and downloading to show as a thumbnail/preview of said image.

Here are some screenshots to help with understanding.
All but the first image in the array change type to application/octet-stream.
only 02_b.png & 02_c.png are in the imageArray

When the user uploads a file They look like this
[When user uploads images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foGtG.png)

When the user presses "Submit" the files look like this
[When user has pressed Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvzrM.png)

I've tried doing something along the lines of Promise.all and looping through the array and going await getDownloadURL with the correct storeage ref. I best guess is that it's somewhere within the submit function and the way i'm saving everything at once.

Here is a screenshot of the data that gets saved into the firebase collection
[Firebase collection data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZF8s.png)

My Submit function code looks something like this

```
const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(
    storage,
    `${loggedInUser[0].user_id}/` + 'images/' + `${title}/` + imageName
);
const imagesList = await listAll(storageRef);

// Get download URLs for each image
const imageUrls = await Promise.all(
    imagesList.items.map(async (storageRef) => {
        const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
        console.log(downloadUrl);
        return downloadUrl;
    })
);

console.log('listingImage', listingImage);
console.log('image array', imageArray);

const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'setups'), {
    title: title,
    description,
    listingImage: imageUrl,
    images: imageArray,
    styles: styleArray,
    colours: colourArray,
    products: productArray,
    ownerId: loggedInUser[0].user_id,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    slug: title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-') + '-by-' + loggedInUser[0].username,
    featured: false,
    approved: false,
    createdBy: loggedInUser[0].username,
    user: loggedInUser[0].username
});
```

To summarize, i'm not sure as to why the type changes from images/png to application/octet-stream when pressing the submit button.

Im not sure if I'm on the right path either, so any help would be amazing.